# Villagers Farming Crops on Minecraft Xbox One Edition

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

How can I get villagers to farm crops on Minecraft Xbox One Edition? According to the Minecraft [Console Edition History](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Console_Edition_version_history) the latest version of Minecraft is **CU10** as of March 2015.

PC tutorials show that you need to [trade](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading) with the villagers to give them the crops they need to plant and then they go around farming automatically. According to [this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading/Before_1.8), the ability to give villagers these items exists as of version **1.8**.

The differences between the console edition and pc version, according to [Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Console_Edition), do not list villager trading / farming. I would have thought this would be a significant difference to list, if it existed.

What I'm trying to figure out is, how does version 1.8 fit with version CU10 - if we can't get villagers to farm, how far off are we from this version-wise? Is there a proposed update in the works for this? Are there any alternative methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about a new Minecraft update by watching Major Nelson's "this week on xbox" and used the above link to check out the changelog - and there it is!

Finally, as of *December 8th 2015*, the update [TU-31](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Console_Edition_version_history#xbox-TU31), which equates to 1.8, listed the following change:

> Villagers have additional professions and trades, **will now harvest crops if they are farmers**, will only breed when willing and will turn into witches when struck by lightning.

About bloody time.

Answer (score 1):

Villager Farming is not possible on the Console Version of Minecraft as of version TU22/CU10.

Have a look at the changelog for [Villagers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#History). The PC version has the following entry, under 1.8 (14w04a):

> Farmer (profession) villagers now harvest fully grown crops

Contrarily, this is absent from the changelog for the console version. In fact, villagers have not been updated since TU14, which is (very) roughly equivalent to PC version 1.3.1 according to the [Version Overview](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Console_Edition_version_history#TU14).

Answer (score 1):

I have Xbox one with the latest version of minecraft.

I built a village and turned two zombies into villagers using the golden apple and weakness potion.

Soon those became many.  Out of the 14 villagers I now have, only one is a farmer.

I was disappointed to see he walked right over the plowed garden and never planted.  I had traded with him many times and yet no planting.

Finally, desperate and even sarcastically I threw seeds at him and spouted a profanity and commanded him to plant.

Suddenly the seeds disappeared as food does when you toss it to a villager

He immediately commenced planting my very large field.

Now my automatic farm will truly be self sufficient,  provided he doesn't run out of seeds.